# How to read a Drupal 7 node as a css file?

Tags: theming

I know that this isn't how Drupal is meant to be used, but I have this special case where I created a node that ends in a .css extension and need to have that file be used as the css file for the whole website.

So what I've got are:

1. a node named styles.css residing at the url "http://www.mysite.com/styles.css"
2. all of my regular nodes linking to that file. the "" is hardcoded into page.tpl.php

Drupal appears not to read styles.css as a css file; any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you know that Drupal isn't meant to be used this way, then why would you do it? Are you trying to allow the end user to edit the CSS through the UI? There are better tools for that! (eg. [Live CSS](http://drupal.org/project/live_css), [Sweaver](http://drupal.org/project/sweaver), [Live Themer](http://drupal.org/project/livethemer)...)

If you update your question and tell us which problem you're trying to solve, we can help you much better.